display custom error message returned from /validate endpoint inside marketing cloud journey builder canvas
i am validating custom activity user selected configuration inside /validate endpoint implementation, from there i want to return informative error message to be shown inside journey builder canvas so that marketer would be aware of what went wrong, instead just showing.
if anyone suggesting client side validation, i need to do only server side validation.

A custom activity or entry source failed validation. Check to ensure that the activity or entry source publishes to a valid endpoint.

